# Total of different currencies from a json file

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

Currently working on an application which requires to display a set of values in different currencies. This is part of an application but everything I provide here should be enough as this is the main section I am working with. I have a json file which is read in and it is stored into an array called `valuesArray`, this array has all the information, such as the amount, currency, etc. With the currencies being sorted with highest first to the lowest on display like this:

```
EUR 500.00
USD 200.00
```

This is the code that I have created but it seems like this wouldn't be effective the more currencies I have. I've just put an array declaration above the function but just above this function is where I do all the json stuff and adding it into the array. `$scope.valuesArray` has data at this point.

```
$scope.valuesArray =[];
$scope.total = function()
    {
        var eur_total   = 0;
        var usd_total   = 0;

        if (typeof $scope.valuesArray != 'undefined')
        {   
            var length = $scope.valuesArray.length; 

            for (var i = 0; i<length ; i++)
            {   
                switch($scope.valuesArray[i].currency)
                {
                    case "USD":
                        usd_total += parseFloat($scope.valuesArray[i].value);
                        break;
                    default:
                        eur_total += parseFloat($scope.valuesArray[i].value);
                        break;
                }
            }
        }   
        var cost_total= [usd_total,eur_total];
        total.sort(function(a, b){return b-a});

        return format_to_decimal(total[0]) + "\x0A" + format_to_decimal(total[1]);
    }
```

In my for loop I go through every single data in the array and break each currency down within the switch statement and finding the total amount of each currencies.

The last bit is kind of temporary as I couldn't figure out a different way of how to do it. I sort the totals for the currencies I have from the highest at the top.

I return the function with a function call for `format_numeric_with_commas` which gives me the value in proper currency format and this displays the value. Will update this and add that code when I get to it. But I have used the indexes as a rough logic to show what I want to get out of it. So in this case, `total[0]` should be `500.00` and `total[1]` should be `200.00`.

On top of this I want to be able to display the currency type for each. So like the example above.

Comment: Is not `$scope.valuesArray` an array? Should it be `var length = $scope.valuesArray.length`? I can't see your array. Might as well show us all the pertinent parts of your `$scope` object.

Comment: @PHPglue Sorry yes, I've edited it. Accidently deleted a couple of things when tidying it. Thanks for pointing it out. I've just put an array declaration above the function but just above this function is where I do all the json stuff and adding it into the array. `$scope.valuesArray` has data at this point.

Comment: I'm not really sure what the question is here? Do you need to perform a Natural Sort?

Comment: @PHPglue Take the data from the json, it has the currency and amount attribute. Separate the currencies and add the totals for each currency. Sort the different totals together so that the highest is at the top and display it with appropriate currency label. i.e. `total[0]` is euros therefore something like `"EUR " + total[0]` = `EUR 300.00` for a simple way but that would mean I would need to know what is in each index and label it with strings making the line longer depending on the the amount of currencies.

Comment: `Math.max.apply(null, arrayHere)` will give you the highest number in an array.

Comment: How would I go about displaying it if I had `EUR = 900.00` `USD = 300.00` `AUD = 700.00`? Cause what I currently do is use the indexes to manually display these. Wouldn't that just return euros being the highest?

Comment: Show us `$scope.valuesArray`. "display like this" is really unclear. Things don't just display. What does that mean? Are those variables in your last comment or part of the Array that you've failed to show us?

Comment: This function is called and it retuns the called values at the end which is printed out/displayed onto the application. `$scope.valuesArray` is the main array which holds all the unsorted data which. It's just example variables yes. Those represent the total of each currencies. I have the unsorted array, it checks in the switch statement which currency it is, it adds it to the total variable for the currency. After this, I sort it so that the highest is first.

Comment: We need an actual example Array, not some code that is supposed to be something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to save all the calculations in the array with currency index.

```
$scope.valuesArray = [];
$scope.total = function () {
var totalsArray = [];
if (typeof $scope.valuesArray != 'undefined') {
    var length = $scope.valuesArray.length
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if (!totalsArray[$scope.valuesArray[i].currency]) {
            totalsArray[$scope.valuesArray[i].currency] = 0;
        }
        totalsArray[$scope.valuesArray[i].currency] += $scope.valuesArray[i].value;

    }
}
var cost_total = [];
for (var k in totalsArray) {
    cost_total.push(currency:k,value:totalsArray[k]);
}
cost_total.sort(function (a, b) {
    return b.value - a.value
});

return format_to_decimal(cost_total[0].value)+cost_total[0].currency + "\x0A" + format_to_decimal(cost_total[1].value);
```

Comment: I tried this but when I use the console it is giving me NaN for the values.

Comment: Do you have any ideas?

Comment: sorry, updated. With this approach you can have as many currencies as you want.

Comment: This removes the currency title for each value doesn't it? When it gets pushed into the array?

Comment: Updated with saved currency. Does it solve your problem?

Comment: I get a `SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list` on `currency:k`